# How to close Laravel show with error info?

Tags: php, laravel

I send AJAX request(GET) to POST API, the error is show:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

This nice working.

But, if i setting `APP_ENV=prod` & `APP_DEBUG=true` to `.env` file, then run the test code, the error is show again.

I'm want to know what happen, thanks.

---

System: Windows 7 64bit
PHP version: 7.2.8 64bit ZTS
Laravel version: 5.6

This's my .env file:

```php
APP_NAME=NiceKingdom
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64:qrCfm9hckUV2n7Le87IEHDht+7WVJQ5fkEn6QHim9lU=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://www.nice-kingdom.uio

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nice_kingdom
DB_USERNAME=nice_kingdom
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.163.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=UioSun@163.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=111e22
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: If this `APP_KEY` is from your production site, be sure to generate a new one now that this one is on the internet.

Comment: Set ```APP_DEBUG=false``` if you want to close the error message

Comment: @AdlanArifZakaria oh! I'm sorry, this code copy from my local file, this's my error...

Comment: @TravisBritz I reload my production server cache, now, this nice working, Thanks!